# perforce automatic p4 edit command on w! on vim

Tags: unix, vim, perforce, perforce-client-spec

Currently my team is facing some issue in perforce , they generally change the file in gvim and close the file without doing p4 edit for that file and due to this when they submit , sometime there some changes do not reflect on server which causes big failure for the same , so can you tell me the way like when i give command w! in vim the system will check that it is inside perforce server then do p4 edit automatically and then edit file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use vim with Perforce, and am very satisfied with the [perforce vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=240). The plugin prompts me every time I edit a file (files in my P4 workspace are read-only by default) and asks me whether I want to check out (`p4 edit`) the file. Thus, every file I touch ends up in my default changelist.

Of course, the plugin can do much more. `p4 submit`, `p4 add`, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s what I do:

```
function P4Checkout()
    call system("p4 edit " . expand("%:p"))
    if v:shell_error == 0
        echom "File " . expand("%:p") . " opened for edit"
        set noreadonly
    endif
endfunction

augroup p4
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileChangedRO * call P4Checkout()
    autocmd BufWritePre * :if &readonly | call P4Checkout()
augroup END
```

This invokes "p4 edit" on the shell whenever either a read-only file is modified for the first time (so no need to save first), or when it is forcefully written to disk (with w!).

As you can probably see, this will only work if p4 edit can actually be run from inside vim in the current working directory. Also, the p4 environment might need tweaking for people working on different repos/streams, etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using 'p4 reconcile' instead of 'p4 edit'.

This command will look for files in the workspace that have been changed, and open them for move, add, edit, delete etc.

More info is located here:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_reconcile.html

Hope this helps,
Jen!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-perforce-love-story

it will pop up a prompt asking whether it is for p4 edit in vim when you try to edit and save the file with (w!).

Example:
:w!
File is read only. Attempt to open in Perforce?
[Y]es, (N)o:

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.